# Create a dynamic task list in Google Sheets for a team w/ Arrayformula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

## Problem I'm trying to solve:

I am trying to create a dynamic task-list.

As of now, I am using [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12fEt2e_vwBbL5qe3KyGfyuz_Qf8q0NtjFbK-x97X1CY/edit?usp=sharing).

---

In this task-list I have main tasks, assigned to a user based on a label.

Example Labels:

- A = Amanda's Work
- B = bob's Work
- C = Candice's Work"

---

Each task can have multiple sub-tasks, and these sub-tasks can also have labels.

In case a sub-tasks does not have a label explicitly set, it should use the label of the main task.

This is done via the "Hidden Helper Column", as seen here:

[image: hidden helper column in action]

---

I want then to have separate sheets (on the same spreadsheet) for each label.

These worksheets need to have the corresponding tasks from my main task list.

**Important:** If a sub-task has a different label than the main task, only that sub-task should show up on the label's list, not including the main task.

[image: example task with sub-task with different label]

[image: example results based on the rule above]

---

## What I want to accomplish:

I want to create the dynamic sheets for each label with the correct tasks assigned to them.

## What I have tried so far:

### Custom formula for Hidden-Helper:

Did not work as expected.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(len(B3:B)=1,B3:B,
    if(len(E3:E)=0,A2:A,
)))
```

### Apps Script `onEdit` routine

Unsatisfactory performance.

```
function SetMarker(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(""Life"");

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("The Last Row # is "+lastRow);
  var startCell = 3; //Cell to begin work.
  Logger.log(" The Starting Cell # is "+startCell);
  var cell ;
  Logger.log(cell);

  for (var i = startCell; i <= lastRow; i++){
    var j = i -1;
    cell = sheet.getRange(i,1);
    Logger.log(""The Cell is ""+cell);
    cell.setFormula("=IF(F"+i+"=\"W\",\"W\",IF(B"+i+"=\"W\",\"W\",IF(E"+i+",\"\",IF(F""+j+"=\""W\"",\"\",A"+j+"))))");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Comment: I've edited your question to follow the guidelines on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your problem and came up with a solution that works without being slow or being too complicated to change.

## Solution

### Components

To achieve a satisfactory result I've decided to use Apps Script.

My [test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1owILF2cVHr5bqBa5AYNpIM9_B7JP2ZFjiKZSH6itn5k/edit?usp=sharing) is like this:

**Labels** (You can hide this sheet)

[image: labels sheet]

**Template Sheet** (You can hide this sheet)

Note the "" keyword there is meant to be replaced by the script

I've taken the liberty to filtering it down to avoid some confusion with the extra columns as well.

[image: template sheet]

**Master Task List**

[image: master task list]

### The Code:

```
var spreadsheetId = "1owILF2cVHr5bqBa5AYNpIM9_B7JP2ZFjiKZSH6itn5k";
var labelSheetName = "Labels";
var mainTaskListName = "Master Task List";
var templateSheetName = "Template Sheet";

/**
Returns a list of Labels in the format:
[0] - Label 
[1] - Sheet Name
@returns array<string> list of labels with corresponding sheet name.
*/
function getLabels() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(labelSheetName).getDataRange().getValues();
  values.shift();
  return values;
}

/**
Returns a list of tasks from the main task list in the format:
[0] - Assigned Label 
[1] - Task Number
[2] - Task name
[3] - Sub-task name
@returns array<string> list of task with their completed information.
*/
function readTasks() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(mainTaskListName).getDataRange().getValues();
  values.shift();
  
  var currentTaskLabel = null;
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    //Does this row have a defined label?
    if (values[i][0]==null || values[i][0] == "") {
      //No. Is this a Main task?
      if (values[i][2]!=null && values[i][2] != "") {
        //Main task, set the currentTaskLabel
        currentTaskLabel = values[i][0];
      } else { //No, use the currentTaskLabel.
        values[i][0] = currentTaskLabel;
      }
    } else {
      //Yes, use this label for the data.
      //Is this a main Taks or a sub-task?
      if (values[i][2]!=null && values[i][2] != "") {
        //Main task, set the currentTaskLabel
        currentTaskLabel = values[i][0];
      } //Sub-Task, do nothing
    }
  }
  
  Logger.log(values);
  return values;
}

/**
Removes existing sheets for labels and creates new ones with correct structure.
*/
function prepareSheet() {
  //Find all the labels
  var labelsSheets = getLabels().map(function(label) {return label[1]});
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  for (var i=0; i<labelsSheets.length; i++) {
    //Remove the sheets
    if (spreadsheet.getSheetByName(labelsSheets[i]) != null) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(labelsSheets[i]));
    //Create new sheets based of template
    var newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(templateSheetName).copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(labelsSheets[i]);
    newSheet.createTextFinder("<SHEET NAME>").replaceAllWith(labelsSheets[i]);
  }
}

/**
Inserts the tasks from the task list into the correct sheet
@param {object} the label representation based on `getLabels`
@param {object} the task list representation based on `readTasks`
*/
function insertTasks(labelRepresentation, fullTaskList) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(labelRepresentation[1]);
  
  var label = labelRepresentation[0];
  
  var filteredTaskList = fullTaskList.filter(function(task) {return task[0]==label});
  filteredTaskList = filteredTaskList.map(function(task) {return [task[1],task[2],task[3]]}); //Remove the label from the output
  
  for (var i=0; i<filteredTaskList.length; i++) {
      var newRow = sheet.appendRow(filteredTaskList[i]).getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
      //If this is a main task, paint the row background
      if (filteredTaskList[i][0]!=null && filteredTaskList[i][0]!="") {
        newRow.setBackground("#B7FFCD");
      } else {
        newRow.setBackground("#FFFFFF");
      }
  }
}

/**
Insert all tasks into the corresponding sheets, after preparing them.
*/
function insertAllTask() {
  var labels = getLabels();
  var tasks = readTasks();
  
  prepareSheet();
  
  for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
    insertTasks(labels[i], tasks);
  }
}
```

### Setting it all up:

To tie it all together, I've created a time-based trigger to run this function every 5 minutes.

[image: time-based trigger]

This way, you won't be stopped while Apps Script is processing your data.

## Future improvements

- The Label column on Master Task List could be a list based on the values from the Labels sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Your post here (screenshots) and comments in your code were very clear. I was able to understand the code then modify it quickly. Your method of arriving to my desired result using apps script instead of complex array formulas was very astute.